# How to send image from one activity to another in kitkat android?

Tags: java, android, image, send, android-4.4-kitkat

In first Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
i.putExtra("image", bytes);
startActivity(i);
```

In second Activity:

```
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

if (bmp != null) {         
    iv_1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

This is working for all devices and versions. But it is not working for Kitkat, why?
How to solve the issue in kitkat?

Comment: Why can't you save the image temperarly and send the path insted of this??

Comment: i want captured image and another image(both images) pass at a time to next activity.how can i pass.

Comment: Yoy can save two images in some external folder and pass the name. If the number is specific, you can fex the image name like temp_1, temp_2

Answer (score 0):

Passing such a huge file through intent is not a good practice. It would slow down the process of launching new activity.

Try to make a static reference of the image and use it in the next activity. As soon as you are done, just make it `null`

Answer (score 0):

Make a singleton class with a `Map<String, Bitmap>` which will keep all images you need, and through intent send just their key names.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good for performance to pass Bitmaps from on activity to another.

Just try to save the bitmap in memory and send "Path" of bitmap to another activity and then just use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);`method in another activity to get bitmap from path.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity convert imageview to bitmap

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

in second activity

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Its working on kitkat also.

Comment: i want captured image and another image passing at a time  to next activity.how can i pass.

Comment: You can also pass captured image as it is to the next activity.

Comment: If am do like above code it shows FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION.if am do like my question,it directly closed in only kitkat. how can i solve this